# Aligning center menu options which are in ul tags

Tags: css, html, menu, html-lists

I want to centre align the menus , I tried using text-align but still no result

Following is the html code:

```
<div id="menu" class="clearfix">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="{$base_url}/index.php">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="{$base_url}/recent/">WATCH</a></li>
    <li><a href="{$base_url}/tags/">TAGS</a></li>
    <li><a href="{$base_url}/channels/">CHANNELS</a></li>
  </ul>
  <br style="clear:both">
</div>
```

And the css used:

```
#menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #515152;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("./images/menu.gif");
}

#menu ul {
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

#menu li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

You have `float:left` on the `li`. Take that line out:

```
#menu li {
  display: inline;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Since you don't need float anymore, you can also get rid of the `<br style="clear:both">` as it'll just put a blank line below the menu now.

Here's a tutorial on [how to properly use float](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/float.php).

> Floating is often used to push an image to one side or another, while
>   having the text of a paragraph wrap around it

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
 #menu ul{
   text-align:center;
 }
```

and then set

```
#menu li{
  margin:0px auto;
}
```

This will leave top and bottom margins as 0px but will automatically detect the left and right margins and make them equal and centered.

Also, remove

```
float:left;
```

from

```
#menu li
```

Comment: You don't need either of those first two changes. Menu already has text align center, and that will apply to its children as well. Margin 0 auto is unnecessary because once you remove the float, it's already centered. It also wouldn't work here, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to center the contents of your #menu tag with the text-align:center. This won't work because you have the 'ul' inside it. What I would do is remove the text-align:center from the #menu tag.

Then in the '#menu ul' tag I would add:

```
margin: 0 auto; /* this will center the UL, but needs to be used with a width set */
width: 500px; /* change this to the width you desire */
```

In order for a block level element to be centered on a page you need to provide a width that is smaller than the width of the parent element it is nested in and then set the margin to be auto for the left and right sides.